# How to read a delimited txt file and populate my database? - C# WindowsForms

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, import

I'm building an app that needs to read a delimited text file and populate some table in my database (SQL Server) with these data.

I've set the delimiter as: ¬

An example of data inside the file that I need to import:

OLD_CLASS¬OLD_NUM¬OLD_SUB_NUM¬NEW_CLASS¬NEW_NUM¬NEW_SUB_NUM
ZETMODEM¬750000595588¬0¬ZETMODEM¬710000003092¬0
ZETMODEM¬750000991145¬0¬ZETMODEM¬750000003980¬0
ZETMODEM¬750000570809¬0¬ZETMODEM¬710000003092¬0
ZETMODEM¬750000493550¬0¬ZETMODEM¬750000000001¬0

What is the best (easier) way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You just need a string splitter. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: you should do a google search on the following `C# Stackoverflow string.Split` and you will find tons of working examples.. it's very easy function to use also if you have any existing code in regards to what you have tried.. please post it..

Comment: You could use [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a delimiter, is that you don't have particular *checks and bounds* from code.  For instance, it is incredibly easy for your data to appear out of sync.  Incorrect column for instance:

```
Example - Demonstration - Format
e - d - f
e - d
e - d - f
```

If you do a simple `split('-');` then you would in essence split incorrectly.  You'll need to create a series of projection, to ensure the column and row data match correctly.  This is a simple approach, but I won't detail the sanitizing of your data.

```
public class Row
{    
     public Row(string content)
     {
          var item = content.Split('-', StringSplitOptions.None);
          Example = item[0];
          Demonstration = item[1];
          Format = item[2];
     }

     public string Example { get; set; }
     public string Demonstration { get; set; }
     public string Format { get; set; }
}
```

Now that you have an approach to separate your *rows* you would simply do some form of reading on your stream.  Then you would call your `Row` while inserting into the database.  You could also do this through Linq, Sql, and several other approaches.

Comment: wouldn't it be best to make a `List<T of Class>` that represents the file structure and implement the  creating of the new class instance when adding to the `List<T>` in regards to holding the parsed Data

Comment: @MethodMan That would be one approach, however this approach is physically using a class with a Constructor / Property.  Those properties are building a model of said data, so as you loop through calling that class each time, the property values should always change allowing you some accuracy with your rows assuming a value exist correctly.

Comment: I see your point I am use to seeing it done a little different your approach will also work, a few ways to do this ..I am not disputing your approach after further / deeper reading of your code..

Comment: Yeah, it is a matter of preference.

Comment: `plus one` I think it should do what the OP needs assuming the OP understands your example .